# Regex - Target <td> containing formatting of date - get all content in that <td>

Tags: python, regex

I have a web page that contains a `<td>` tag, for example

```
<td>Aug 17, 2017 02:00 PM EDT</td>
```

I'm trying to use regex to find content in the page matching the format of `,` then a `space` then `four numbers` then a `space` then `two numbers` then `:` then `two numbers` `space` `two capital letters` `space` `three capital letters`. Just to make sure I always target that date and not accidentally get something else.

I don't think another instance of that format would ever occur, but I'd want the first instance. I guess I could just grab the `[0]` position in the returned variable to be sure I get the correct date.

I'm have the following regex so far:

```
(?=\,\s\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s[A-Z]{3})(.*)(?=\<\/td)
```

So, in python code:

```
date = re.findall(r'(?=\,\s\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s[A-Z]{3})(.*)(?=\<\/td)', page)
print(date[0])
```

This gets me close, but not quite all the way. It gets me

```
, 2017 02:00 PM EDT
```

Whereas I need

```
Aug 17, 2017 02:00 PM EDT
```

But I can't figure out how to extend the regex to grab all of the td. Thanks for any help!

(btw, Python 3)

***Edit*** *adding decode*

```
page = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but you're going to want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a regex group to match `Aug 17, 2017 02:00 PM EDT` between the `td` tags:

```
import re
s = "<td>Aug 17, 2017 02:00 PM EDT</td>"
new_s = re.findall('<td>([a-zA-Z]+\s\d+,\s\d{4}\s[0-9\:]+\s[a-zA-Z\s]+)</td>', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'Aug 17, 2017 02:00 PM EDT'
```

Comment: Great thank you, very straight forward and works perfectly! For things like `<td>` I don't have to escape `<` like `\<`, right?

Comment: @Kenny Glad to help! You are correct, `<` and `>` do not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to grab all the content before the first comma.

```
<td>(?=.*\,\s\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s[A-Z]{3})(.*)(?=\<\/td)
```

Also, you have to put the opening  in the regex before your group, so the regex won't grab it.

Regex101 test:
https://regex101.com/r/yxqE6Q/1